# How to send and receive USSD codes with ionic platform?

Tags: ionic-framework, cross-platform, ussd

I'm a junior developer in  Ionic platform, now I have a problem to send and receive USSD codes with that .... please help me is you know about that.

Comment: could you clarify more on sending and receiving USSD codes, you mean being able to interact with USSD menus?

Answer (score 4):

From what I have found on internet and tested,
you can send USSD codes

```
<a href="tel:YOUR_NUMBER" class="button button-positive">Call me? </a>
```

and to make it functional you need to provide access in CONFIG.XML, simple add

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

only disadvantage is: it will not directly dial your number rather open it in default Dailer of device.

Note: I'm newbie here on Stack so don't know formal ways of answering.
have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Call Number](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number/) native plugin. It allows you to make phone calls and send USSD codes. On Android, it sends the USSD codes directly, without launching a phone app.

1. Install the plugin as explained in the docs.
2. Use it to send USSD codes.

**Example:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CallNumber } from "@ionic-native/call-number";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  template: `
    <button ion-button (click)="callNumber()">CallNumber</button>
  `
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public phone: CallNumber) { }

  callNumber(){
    this.phone.callNumber("123456789", true)
      .then(res => this.result = res)
      .catch(err => this.result = err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this allow you to do the USSD dialog resulting from the call? And receive the data?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for this, you can use this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ussd

npm i cordova-plugin-ussd

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ussd

In you ts file add under imports: declare var ussd: any;
and use the dial function

if your phone support double SIM and you don’t have a second SIM card
change the line 36 in yourProject\plugins\ng.neiel.cordova.plugins.ussd\src\android\Ussd.java to
TelephonyManager manager2 = SIM2_id != null ? manager.createForSubscriptionId(SIM2_id.getSubscriptionId()) : null;
and reinstall cordova platform

make sure you have the CALL_PHONE permission