# How Sending and receiving USSD codes using Ionic Typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ussd

Im learning Ionic 2 Framework, and Im searching about executing USSD codes using Ionic Typescript. Can AnyOne help me to find something useful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196136/how-to-send-and-receive-ussd-codes-with-ionic-platform

Answer (score 1):

There is a Cordova plugin you can use to send USSD codes.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-globeconnect

Here is a different google search result that looks good

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/dialing-ussd-with-ionic2/73127

Remember, Ionic is nothing more than a HTML5 framework.  To interact with any hardware, Ionic must use Cordova.  There are a good number of Cordova plugins available.  To interact with the Cordova plugin from within Ionic, you should investigate Ionic Native.